# performSegueWithIdentifier is leaking memory arc

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am very new to iOS development.  My app seems to be piling up dead memory. The only thing I can trace it back to is `performSegueWithIdentifier` function.

```
- (IBAction)segueNext:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueForward" sender:self];
}
```

Here are some screenshots from my analysis.

[image: Heapshot image]

[image: Leak Image]

Am I not performing this method call correctly? Or how do I release this when I'm using ARC?
Thank you for any suggestions you have!

Comment: Share some code if possible.Thanks.

Comment: What other code would you like to see? I can post my .h and .m files if you'd like. Just let me know what would be helpful to you

Comment: First, are you using ARC or not? What about your segue controller?

Comment: I am using ARC for this project. For the seque I have Control Clicked under the storyboard scene, connected it to the desired scene I want to segue to, then labled the segue identifier @"segueForward". Is this the proper ways to set this up?

Comment: The segue sends you to a new view controller...what do you do when you're finished with it?  (Is it push or modal?)

Comment: It is a push segue to a scene with the same custom view controller class as this one. This part of the app is a presentation which most scenes are almost identical and do not need their own class. However, I have tried to give each scene its own class and have not seen any difference in leaking.

Comment: Well if you keep pushing and never dismiss anything then it's going to keep stacking up new instances, this could be what is happening here.

Comment: I see your point. What do you suggest I do when I want to have a presentation style app with many slides?